# How to format JSON list response in Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

I am creating an API as a personal project for a game I really enjoy. I am trying to figure out how to encapsulate each member of the JSON list with a particular value from each member.

For example, my response looks like this:

```json
[
    [
        {
            "createdAt": "2021-08-21T05:04:45.000+00:00",
            "updatedAt": "2021-08-21T05:04:45.000+00:00",
            "id": 1,
            "cardName": "Demon Fiend",
            ...
        },
        {
            "createdAt": "2021-08-21T05:04:58.000+00:00",
            "updatedAt": "2021-08-21T05:04:58.000+00:00",
            "id": 2,
            "cardName": "Stack",
            ...
        },
        {
            "createdAt": "2021-08-21T05:05:00.000+00:00",
            "updatedAt": "2021-08-21T05:05:00.000+00:00",
            "id": 3,
            "cardName": "Overflow",
            ...
        }
    ]
]
```

And, the ideal response would index them by either their cardName or id, like so:

```json
[
    [
        "Demon Fiend" : {
            "createdAt": "2021-08-21T05:04:45.000+00:00",
            "updatedAt": "2021-08-21T05:04:45.000+00:00",
            "id": 1,
            "cardName": "Demon Fiend",
            ...
        },
        "Stack" : {
            "createdAt": "2021-08-21T05:04:58.000+00:00",
            "updatedAt": "2021-08-21T05:04:58.000+00:00",
            "id": 2,
            "cardName": "Stack",
            ...
        },
        "Overflow" : {
            "createdAt": "2021-08-21T05:05:00.000+00:00",
            "updatedAt": "2021-08-21T05:05:00.000+00:00",
            "id": 3,
            "cardName": "Overflow",
            ...
        }
    ]
]
```

I think this would make it a lot easier for users to iterate through the data. Again, the "Demon Fiend" could just be `1 : { ... }`

Comment: if you want to transform in MySQL itself you can use `JSON_OBJECTAGG` and `JSON_OBJECT`

Comment: you can create map of `Map<Integer, UserData> memberIdMap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON response you are getting is invalid - I recommend validate JSON using - [[JSON Formatter]](https://jsonformatter.org/)

Here is the code for your solution, Change **siteInfo[i].cardName** with whatever value you want to use e.g. cardName, id... (i used cardName in below code).

Enjoy! :)

```js
var siteInfo =
  [
    {
      "createdAt": "2021-08-21T05:04:45.000+00:00",
      "updatedAt": "2021-08-21T05:04:45.000+00:00",
      "id": 1,
      "cardName": "Demon Fiend"
    },
    {
      "createdAt": "2021-08-21T05:04:58.000+00:00",
      "updatedAt": "2021-08-21T05:04:58.000+00:00",
      "id": 2,
      "cardName": "Stack"
    },
    {
      "createdAt": "2021-08-21T05:05:00.000+00:00",
      "updatedAt": "2021-08-21T05:05:00.000+00:00",
      "id": 3,
      "cardName": "Overflow"
    }
  ]

var map = new Map();
for(var i=0; i<siteInfo.length; i++) {
  map.set(siteInfo[i].cardName, siteInfo[i]);
}
let jsonObject = {}; 
  map.forEach((value, key) => {  
    jsonObject[key] = value  
  });  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
```

Answer (score 0):

I must confess your question is bit confusing to me.

I am assuming that you are returning a list of objects in your controller as the response.
Like this,

```
public List<YourDtoClass> ...
```

If that's the case what you can do is return a **Map** instead.
Like this,

```
public Map<String, YourDtoClass>
```

If you already created a List, you can crate Map as follows,

```
return yourList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(YourDtoClass::getCardName, Function.identity()));
```

Answer (score -1):

let this is your Class named SampleClass

```
   

     class SampleClass {
            "createdAt": "2021-08-21T05:04:45.000+00:00",
            "updatedAt": "2021-08-21T05:04:45.000+00:00",
            "id": 1,
            "cardName": "Demon Fiend",
            ...
      }
```

instead of using array of objects, use a map with key as "cardName" and value as SampleClass. then you will get the desired form.

Comment: then how do you make this json? It is not clearly mentioned in the question. Please narrow down your question.